# Accessing sharepoint from caml

Tags: sharepoint, caml

How can I add javascript to my CAML code?

For example, I want to calculate some rates/dates according to local field on Sharepoint list.

I want to set value of field according to the javascript result.

Any Idea ?

Poli .

Answer (score 0):

You can add JavaScript to your page, not to CAML.
CAML is used to query Sharepoint lists.
The results will be rendered as HTML
Have a look at the rendered HTML and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "add" javascript code to a CAML query because CAML queries run on the server where as javascript runs client side.

Say you have a query like this :

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FieldName' /><Value Type='Text'>TestValue</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

When you run your query :

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

You will end up with your items. This is where you can modify them and run your logic code (in your backend code).

For example :

foreach(SPListItem item in SPListItemCollection)
{
    int rate = item["SomeField"].ToString() + item["SomeOtherField"].ToString();
    //Do whatever you want with the result
}